# Code explanation to determine whether a class is derived from another class

Tags: c++, c++11

The intention is to detect whether the Template type parameter `D` is derived from Template type parameter `B`. The below code has private static methods in the class `IsDerivedHelper`. The question is `How does the static method inside the Helper class works?` It doesn't have a definition in it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<type_traits>

using namespace std;

class IOne
{
private:
public:
    IOne() = delete;
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class One :public IOne
{
public:
    One() = default;
    virtual void print()
    {
        cout << "printed from class One" << endl;
    }
};

class Two
{

};

template<typename D, typename B> class IsDerivedHelper
{
    class No{};
    class Yes { No no[3]; };
    static Yes Test(B*);
    static No Test(...);
public:
    enum { Is = sizeof(Test(static_cast<D*>(0))) == sizeof(Yes) };
};

void main()
{
    auto v = IsDerivedHelper<One, IOne>::Is;    // Value is 1
    // auto v = IsDerivedHelper<Two, IOne>::Is; // Value is 0
    if (v)
    {
        cout << "Is derived" << endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Not a derived." << endl;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The book reviewed [here](https://accu.org/index.php?module=bookreviews&func=search&rid=979) has a complete explanation. Go get it. It's very illuminating, despite its age.

Comment: [`using namespace std;` is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2176813), never use it.

Comment: Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See [ask].

Comment: FYI, C++11 has [`std::is_base_of()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) available: "*checks if a type is derived from the other type*", so `IsDerivedHelper` is not actually needed at all: `auto v = std::is_base_of<IOne, One>::value;`  `auto v = std::is_base_of<IOne, Two>::value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THis works at compile time really , the core is the decision of which `IsDerivedHelper::Test` overload to use

this call here

```
sizeof(Test(static_cast<D*>(0)))
```

Will return the sizeof the return value of which overload is chosen. All at compile time.

The two overloads are

```
   static Yes Test(B*);
    static No Test(...);
```

The first one is used if the argument passed is derived from B.
The second one is used in any other case. `...` means 'any args'

the static methods are never called, everything is evaluated at compile time.

It is a clever set of tricks

Comment: do you know why `No no[3]` is used?

Comment: to force the return size of the two overloads to be different. One return a No the other return 3 No

Comment: why 3, 2 should be enough as well

Comment: works with 2 as well. You will have to ask the original author why they chose 3